# Map flipped on the horizontal Axis when displayed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a problem with displaying maps on screen. I am giving the developer the choice between square tiles and hexagonal tiles. The map is saved as a .txt

The square tiled map displays correctly as shown
[image]

where as the hexagonal map is upside down
[image]

I am completely stumped as to how to go about fixing the issue I have supplied the entire function bellow

```
void displayMap(){

    //Draw Tiles on the Screen

    if (useSquareTiles == true && useHexagonTiles == false) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
                GameObject.Instantiate (mapArray [y] [x], new Vector3 (x, mapHeight - y, 0),
                                        Quaternion.Euler (-90, 0, 0));
            }
        }
    }

    float hexWidth = 0.85f; //The width of the HexTiles
    if (useHexagonTiles == true && useSquareTiles == false) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
                GameObject.Instantiate (mapArray[y][x], new Vector3 (x * hexWidth, y + (0.5f * Mathf.Abs (x) % 1), 0),
                                        Quaternion.Euler (-90, 0, 0));
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: To be pedantic, it's not upside down, it's flipped in the horizontal. Not sure if that helps....

Comment: What happens if you play around with the signs in the second block. Specifically in your `Vector3`?

Comment: I hate coding sometimes... I should have looked at the Y vector in square and I would have realised why its flipped. I had forgotten to subtract the mapHeight first. 

The answer to my problem is: 
(mapHeight - y) + (0.5f * Mathf.Abs (x) %1)

Comment: Not directly related to your question but why use two booleans (`useHexagonTiles` and `useSquareTiles`) while only one would suffice?

Comment: I use the booleans elsewhere detection it makes things easier for checking which set of tiles is in use